# Prolog instantiation error when using two "is/2" predicates

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I'm new to Prolog and wanted to try some basic examples. I saw multiple questions about the instantiation error that Prolog throws, but I couldn't find a solution for my example.

My rule is for updating a location after a `forward` action is executed in a certain direction. I just removed the heading for simplification, it keeps failing:

```
% loc(x, y, t)
loc(1, 1, 1) :- !.  % location at time t = 1
loc(X2, Y, T2) :-  % X1 incremented by 1
    T2 > 1,
    T1 is T2 - 1,
    forward(T1),  % a forward action was executed at the previous time step
    X1 is X2 - 1,
    loc(X1, Y, T1).
```

As I said, this throws the dreaded error:

> ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Usual reminder: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: Thanks @brebs. I had been using `trace` already but I found the output quite intricated. Even at this point, after getting an answer from @slago below, I still don't understand how the trace could help me with this.

Comment: Where did you find this "basic" example? It doesn't make much sense, despite the attempt at an explanation.

Comment: @brebs what exactly you don't understand? Maybe I can answer you here or you can create your own question :)

Comment: E.g. why is your `loc/3` calling itself? If you want to increment an integer, just use e.g. `X1 is X + 1` - why are you involving recursion here?

Comment: @brebs `loc/3` is calling itself because the current location depends on the previous location. It's a recursive call. I'm updating the question with the `forward` action, maybe that makes more sense to you.

Comment: What purpose is `forward` serving? Why does `loc` have to be recursive? Where does this code come from? Why are you learning Prolog with this strange code, rather than with code that works?

Comment: @brebs `forward/1` is an action to move forward, e.g. `assert(forward(1))` means that the agent moved forward at time t = 1. `loc` is recursive for the reason I already told you: the current location depends on the past locations. I created the code. I'm learning by doing. It's a program for the Wumpus world. I've got it working by the way, an agent for the Wumpus world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `X2` is an output argument. If this is indeed the case, the code should be modified as follows:

```
loc(1, 1, 1) :- !. 
loc(X2, Y, T2) :- 
    T2 > 1,
    T1 is T2 - 1,
    loc(X1, Y, T1),
    X2 is X1 + 1.
```

Example:

```
?- loc(X,Y,3).
X = 3,
Y = 1.
```

Comment: Thanks @slago, this points me in the right direction. Could you please tell me where to find this topic of "output arguments" in the documentation? Cheers.

Comment: @clapas An output argument is an argument that may not be bound at the call-time and that must be instantiated by the callee (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=preddesc). Since `is/2` only instantiates variables that are used as its left operand, an output argument cannot be used in the expression given as its right operand (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2).